# 18.04 suddenly refuses to accept password

Tags: password

Good Day

Yesterday I  installed  18.04 on a new (for me) ASUS E200ha Vivobook. Yesterday all went well but today it suddenly refuses to accept my password.
I am newbie in Linux and need advice how to handle this. Personally at 77 I
do not need passwords at all and would be happy to kill this. I sign on with
none and its when I try to download a new program that I run into this problem.
Thanks in advance for any help

Further Today 1/9.
Hello All and thank you for your comments. I have not forgotten my pword as it is engraved in my brain from many years ago. The disk can not be anywhere full . the OS took 1.8 gigs fully loaded of a 32 Gig disk and I was just starting. I loaded a couple of small programs on day 1. Day 2 was when it started with its nonsense. I disabled passwords & keys  in the system to see if that would help but no. Today I decided to try again and started up ()with a disabled desktop sign in (right from start) opened the Software app and tried to download a new Browser. It hit me with -this password is incorrect in red. 
So I thought more ways to skin a cat and went online and found Oprah browser with instructions for installing. Brought up Terminal and entered instructions. Asked for Password and when I entered it was again told it was not the correct password. I am beginning to think that the easiest way would be for me to reload 18.04 and cross fingers. Any thoughts

Comment: Hi Jim. Is it possible your disk is full? Also, do you get any kind of error message? If so, please tell us the exact message you get.

Comment: I agree with Sebastian.  If your space in $HOME (your user directory) is full, your GUI (graphical user interface) login will be unable to create needed temporary working-files, and thus will get an (internal) error & login will abort; you will be returned to the greeter (login screen) without an actual error. If you CTRL+ALT+F4 to switch to a terminal, and login via text mode, you should be able to login;  A `df -h` will show disk-free (-h means human output)  where the /home directory (if used, otherwise /) "avail" (or available) column is the important bit, ie. space available.

Comment: Continuing...  You only run into this issue when you login (logout or reboot, shut-down).  It could be the last 'new program' you added used enough free disk space to mean you can't login again (which is only a problem once you logged out, or shutdown).  If you have minimal space (eg. my system has 3.3G in /, and 16G in /home for a `df -h` on this workstation) this could be your problem. Edit your question & add the details for your system IF you think this is your issue.  You'll have to select things to delete if this is the case (in your user directory, or anywhere if $HOME isn't separate)

Comment: @guiverc I don't think the OP is having a login problem (*"I sign on with none and its when I try to download a new program that I run into this problem."*) - it sounds more like an issue with a lost or forgotten administrative password

Comment: Hello All and thank you for your comments. I have not forgotten my pword as it is engraved in my brain from many years ago. The disk can not be anywhere full . the OS took 1.8 gigs fully loaded of a 32 Gig disk and I was just starting. I loaded a couple of small programs on day 1. Day 2 was when it started with its nonsense. I disabled keys and  ?? in the system to see if that would help but no.

Comment: Hi All  Thanks for your ideas but since my additional post above I did a reinstall and it seems to have settled down. Running very nicely compared to win 10 was on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem. this is what i did: i just set the keybord to the original language, i mean, the language i used when i was setting the password and it worked. even if the letters and numbers were the same in the two languages, the login only worked if the keyboard was set in english {in my case}.